# Fullcalendar event rendering

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to render an event to take up the entire space in a cell. For instance in the month view.

Out of the box, the date is displayed on top, and then the event underneath. I want to ignore the date text and display the event over the intire cell, I don't want to hardcode the height of the event.

Hope to get some pointers, I have looked everywhere in the javascript and css.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am looking to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you want is that FullCalendar floats the event div over the cell. So you'd need a script to reposition the event to the top of the cell and adjust the event div to match the cell size. This shouldn't be too difficult, but what happens if there is more than one event? Or if an event spans more than one day?